# Dynamic routing based after Resequencing messages

Tags: apache-camel

I want to reorder a sequence of messages and dynamically route the messages according to their order after resequencing. Say, first message after resequencing should be routed to A, and others to route B.

I was able to reorder messages using resequencer, but how do I dynamically route the first message alone to a particular route after resequencing? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from(CAMEL_DIRECT_REORGANISE_MSGS)
        .resequence(header("priority")).batch().timeout(resequencerTimeout * 1000).size(3).reverse()
        .to("direct:A");
```

In above route, all messages out of resequencer flows to RouteA, but I want first message alone to flow to RouteA and the rest to RouteB.

Answer (score 0):

Use recipient list component, it allows you to dynamically pass the endpoint uri in the 'to' endpoint.

Comment: but how do i set recipient list as 'A route' for first element (index 0 of re-sequence batch) alone and as 'B route' for the others, after re-sequencing? because you wont be knowing which element is the first one in re-sequence batch.